# Parse a list of maps from JSON with dynamic keys

Tags: json, dart

I have this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "5e4442a72414233f286d655e": 5
    },
    {
        "5e599a7cbf66db8faeff3e2b": 3
    }
]
```

I would like to parse it so that I end up `List<Map<String, int>>` of something like it that would allow me to access the key and the value, knowing that the key is not a fixed string.

The approach I tried is:

```
jsonDecode(jsonString) as List<Map<String, int>>
```

But I get the following error

```
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, int>>'
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: There is an open issue about this topic: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/31876

Answer (score 0):

`jsonDecode` will type everything it returns as a `dynamic` of some kind, whether it's a `List<dynamic>`, `Map<String, dynamic>` or just `dynamic`. However, just because it's typed that way doesn't mean it can't be cast into the type you want.

```dart
var list = jsonDecode(jsonString) as List;
var castList = list.cast<Map>().map((m) => m.cast<String, int>()).toList();
// castList will be List<Map<String, int>>
```